# MySQL error 1064 (42000) on attempt to create table from the MySQL command line client

Tags: mysql, create-table

[Screen clipping of code and resulting error message][1][Corrected code and resulting error][2]

I am attempting to create a table using multiple lines in the MySQL command line client:

Corrected the below as I had the PRIMARY KEY command in twice. Even after correcting that I still get the error, as per the below...

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE claim (
    -> claim_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> claim_date DATE,
    -> reason VARCHAR(50),
    -> transport_ref VARCHAR(10),
    -> po_ref VARCHAR(10),
    -> nesi_ref VARCHAR(10),
    -> efbs_ref VARCHAR(10),
    -> claim_ref VARCHAR(10),
    -> load_date DATE,
    -> net_weight DECIMAL(8,2),
    -> boxes SMALLINT(4),
    -> claim_currency VARCHAR(3),
    -> insure_value_kg DECIMAL(5,2),
    -> other_costs_kg DECIMAL(5,2),
    -> invoice_number VARCHAR(10),
    -> invoice_date DATE,
    -> invoice_value DECIMAL(10,2),
    -> notes VARCHAR(256)
    -> );
'''

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' TABLE claim (
claim_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
claim_date ' at line 1
mysql>

If I put it all in on one line, then it works:
```

CREATE TABLE claim (claim_id SMALLINT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, claim_date DATE, reason VARCHAR(50), transport_ref VARCHAR(10), po_ref VARCHAR(10), nesi_ref VARCHAR(10), efbs_ref VARCHAR(10), claim_ref VARCHAR(10), load_date DATE, net_weight DECIMAL(8,2), boxes SMALLINT(4), claim_currency VARCHAR(3), insure_value_kg DECIMAL(5,2), other_costs_kg DECIMAL(5,2), invoice_number VARCHAR(10), invoice_date DATE, invoice_value DECIMAL(10,2), notes VARCHAR(256));

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.03 sec)

I need to use multiple lines, otherwise the code gets too complicated. Can anyone help me to understand why my multiple line table creation code isn't working?

PS. If I use the same multiple line code in PopSQL, the table is created without any issue.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3OQt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dznBx.png
```

Comment: It's a dumb question, but is that actually a space in `CREATE TABLE`? If it's some kind of "gremlin" that'd explain this.

Comment: hmm.. multiple primary key defined ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1586400b233f0be30d650b48a49d262

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the CREATE TABLE statement and edited my original post to show the corrected code and I'm still getting the error. I can bypass this by putting the entire statement on one line, but I would really like to understand why this isn't working. Probably a typo on my part, but I've retyped everything a few times and I'm getting exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the queries and none of them gave any errors. Try copying & pasting the code you gave here. Might work. Also you don't need `NOT NULL` for `PRIMARY KEY` because `PRIMARY KEY` enforces `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` by default.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing that out Sathika. I have corrected that and continue to recieve the same error message. Unfortunately, that wasn't what was causing it.

Comment: I've corrected the original question and I also show the error code I'm receiving now. Strange, I know I miss things sometimes, but I'm reallys truggling to find any errors in the CREATE TABLE statement.